# Typo3 7.6 typoscript problems with markers

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I have the following typoscript code

```
page.20 = TEMPLATE
page.20.template = FILE
page.20.template.file = fileadmin/design/index.html
page.20.marks{
    CONTENT < styles.content.get
    CONTENT.renderObj.stdWrap.dataWrap=<div class="col-md-12">|</div>

    CONTENTLEFT < styles.content.getLeft
    #CONTENTLEFT.renderObj.stdWrap.dataWrap=<div class="col-md-5">|</div>

    CONTENTRIGHT< styles.content.getRight
    #CONTENTRIGHT.renderObj.stdWrap.dataWrap=<div class="col-md-7 text">|</div>


    TOPIMAGE< styles.content.getBorder
```

Problem is that `CONTENTLEFT` & `CONTENTRIGHT` & `TOPIMAGE` is not rendered.

I have inserted the Markers like this

`###TOPIMAGE###` and then I've added some content Elements.

What could be the problem? I use Typo3 7.6.19

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have installed css_styled_content, and include static typoscript from extension css_styled_content?

Comment: Yes I have. Added two screenshots above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using static typoscript from EXT:fluid_styled_content, and not css_styled_content.
EXT:fluid_styled_content for TYPO3 7.6 do not have any typoscript styles.content.getLeft or .. getRight. Have a look at

*typo3_src-7.6.23/typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Configuration/TypoScript/Static/Setup/styles.content.get.ts*

or use backendmodul templates and choose 'typosript object browser' to look into your current loaded typosript setup.

If you want use old template marks, you could install EXT:css_styled_content and load static typoscript from this extensions, instead to load fluid_styled_content. Or just find

*typo3_src-7.6.23/typo3/sysext/css_styled_content/static/setup.txt*

and copy the typoscript parts for *styles.content.get..* as you like to use for your example, like

```
# Clear out any constants in this reserved room!
styles.content >

# get content
styles.content.get = CONTENT
styles.content.get {
    table = tt_content
    select.orderBy = sorting
    select.where = colPos=0
}

# get content, left
styles.content.getLeft < styles.content.get
styles.content.getLeft.select.where = colPos=1

# get content, right
styles.content.getRight < styles.content.get
styles.content.getRight.select.where = colPos=2
```